# Php title for web page

Tags: php, web

I have this code on my header.php. Its for creating title on the fly. The problem is that it only creates a title when user is on the article.php(page for reading the article) but produce a 'undefined variable i' error on other pages. What should I change or who know a better code for the title of web page? i is id.

```
   if(isset($i=$_GET['i']) && $i = true ) {  
$i=$_GET['i'];
$tbl_name="yote";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE i='$i'") or die(mysql_error());
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$title = $rows['title']. "";
}
mysql_close();   

   } else { 

         $title = 'Malloooo - News, Reviews, Analysis and Market Watch From Around The World';     
                 } 
?>

<!-- Header
================================================== -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<!-- Basic Page Needs
 ================================================== -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Comment: Warning: Your code is dangerously vulnerable to being hacked by a SQL Injection attack, because you are not escaping your SQL variables properly. Also, off topic but also important: please note that the `mysql_xxx()` family of functions are **deprecated**. It is recommended not to use them, and instead switch to either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries.

Comment: `isset($i=$_GET['i'])` is incorrect. You should not have an assignment `=` inside an `isset()`.

Comment: Please include the complete error message as part of your question. Also, which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @erisco The error is about the 'i' in $_GET['i'], it is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, there's quite a bit wrong with your code.

1. `if (isset($i=$_GET['i']) ...` : Not sure what you're trying to do with that, but it's not valid.
2. `... && $i = true)` : This is setting a value, not checking it.
3. You're horribly vulnerable to SQL injection. Look into PDO: http://php.net/PDO